# Reminder for WeChat Store Service Account user using push notification

Tags: php, laravel, wechat

We are preparing to create a eCommerce website that can be run from WeChat Store. Although there are enough information such as ICP, the developer account for the Tencent SDK, etc, but can't find information on auto-reminder-feature through WeChat app.

For example, my customer may have purchase some product from our new WeChat Store. Then, we want to sent a reminder after X days for them to refill it. Instead of spamming them through email, we were wondering whether we can utilize the push notification feature provided by WeChat Store.

Service account can sent up to 4 push messages per month, but, if we want to sent a custom message for different users, are we allow to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes, provided you have each customers open id